# Modify the original object in Service Fabric Reliable Collections

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections) article about working with Reliable Collections and it is mentioned there **you MUST not modify an object once you have given it to a reliable collection** and the correct way to update a value in a reliable collection, is to get a copy (clone) of the value, checnge the cloned value and then update the cloned value in the RC.

**Bad use:**

```
using (ITransaction tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction()) {
   // Use the user’s name to look up their data
   ConditionalValue<User> user = 
      await m_dic.TryGetValueAsync(tx, name);

   // The user exists in the dictionary, update one of their properties.
   if (user.HasValue) {
      // The line below updates the property’s value in memory only; the
      // new value is NOT serialized, logged, & sent to secondary replicas.
      user.Value.LastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow; // Corruption!
      await tx.CommitAsync(); 
   }
}
```

My Quesion is: why can't I modify the the object once I gave it to the RC? why do I have to clone the object before I change something in it? why can't I do something like (update the object in the same transaction):

```
using (ITransaction tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction()) {
   // Use the user’s name to look up their data
   ConditionalValue<User> user = 
      await m_dic.TryGetValueAsync(tx, name);

   // The user exists in the dictionary, update one of their properties.
   if (user.HasValue) {
      // The line below updates the property’s value in memory only; the
      // new value is NOT serialized, logged, & sent to secondary replicas.
      user.Value.LastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow;

      // Update
      await m_dic.SetValue(tx, name, user.Value);

      await tx.CommitAsync(); 
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Reliable Dictionary is a replicated object store. If you update the objects inside Reliable Dictionary without going through Reliable Dictionary (e.g. [TryUpdateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliabledictionary-2#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_Collections_IReliableDictionary_2_TryUpdateAsync_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_ITransaction__0__1__1_)), then you can corrupt the state.

For example, if you change the object inside Reliable Dictionary using your reference, then the change will not be replicated to the secondary replicas.
This is because Reliable Dictionary does not know that you changed one of the TValues. Hence, the change will be lost if the replica ever fails over.

Above is the most simple example. Modifying objects directly can cause other serious problems like breaking ACID in multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can do what you want. But don't forget about lock modes and isolation levels.
[Here we can read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections): “Any Repeatable Read operation by default takes Shared locks. However, for any read operation that supports Repeatable Read, the user can ask for an Update lock instead of the Shared lock”.

That means that `TryGetValueAsync` gets only Shared lock. And attempt to update this value later could cause a dedlock.
The next statement is: “An Update lock is an asymmetric lock used to prevent a common form of deadlock that occurs when multiple transactions lock resources for potential updates at a later time.”

So, the correct code would be

```
await m_dic.TryGetValueAsync(tx, name, LockMode.Update)
```